# Samsung Galaxy Book S (Intel) Ubuntu 20.04 installation keyboard/touchpad do not work

Tags: dual-boot, keyboard, samsung

I bought an Intel version of Samsung Galaxy Book S recently, and tried to install Ubuntu 20.04 as dual boot along with pre-installed Windows 10.

After I select "Ubuntu" from grub (safe graphics mode and adding command "nomodeset" do not solve the problem) and all the disk checks complete, welcome screen pops up with "Try Ubuntu" and "Install Ubuntu" options available. In that screen, my keyboard and touchpad does not work at all, so I cannot proceed installation. I know that the installation did not actually freeze, because the clock is still changing.

I have all fast startup and secure boot disabled, but I think this is more of a keyboard and touchpad driver issue. Can anyone provide a solution to this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Put an external USB keyboard and mouse on your Samsung Galaxy Book S to finish the installation process, and see what happen. i.e. To see whether Ubuntu 20.04 can put right keyboard and touchpad driver for it.