# I can't install Ubuntu because the installer can't see the SSD in my laptop at all

Tags: boot, dual-boot, storage

I own a Samsung Galaxy Book S. It came with Windows 10 and I wanna change to Ubuntu. I am booting with a installation media that has Ubuntu 20.10 on it. (Fast boot, Secure boot is disabled). GRUB menu appears and I select "Ubuntu" (top option). And it boots just fine.

When I select the "install ubuntu" option in the GUI program that launches it says

"You need atleast 8.6 GB disk space to install Ubuntu, This computer has only 7.7 GB"

.
This is the space off of my USB drive. If I bypass the installation and use it as a LIVE usb, Gparted can't see the SSD drive either.

I have tried Un-allocating space in Win10 , along with partitioning it, with no result.

Alot of people seem to have had the same kind of issue where they only had to change from RAID>AHCI but I don't even have that option in my BIOS menu. (Aptio Setup utility BIOS Version P07AJD)

NOTE I don't mind deleting windows at all, if Ubuntu is the only OS on the laptop it's perfect.
I just have no idea on how to proceed :c

Link to the wall im facing:
https://gyazo.com/a1d8d289b4b06156a4739c0e0c0ab487

Comment: There is a drop down menu at the top-right hand side of gparted where you will see sda. Click it and see if there is sdb or any other drive showing or not?

Comment: Windows sometimes uses dynamic partitions instead of basic, this can also confused Ubuntu.  Some bios requires you to set a password(do not lose) to change some settings.  Windows needs to be prepared if changed from RAID/RST to ACHI or else it gives a hissy fit and won't boot.  Some bios also have secret keys to change, need to google your bios.

Comment: There isn't any other options than the USB drive available in Gparted at all @MOHSINSHAHZAD

Comment: @crip659 From my observation the disk is basic and not dynamic as I still have the option to convert the disk.

https://gyazo.com/67164b63dbae193fc074a25023614fc3

it says "Convert to dynamic disc" in danish.


Also I've googled all I can on the BIOS menu itself, where I can't find any hidden menues containing the option to change from RAID/RST to ACHI. Im assuming this is the culprit.

(The Linux partition was just created as a test to see if it was able to see the new partition, left it unallocated before).

Comment: Found this link for your computer, says might need to an external ssd.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320550/how-do-i-make-the-ssd-accessible-to-the-ubuntu-installer-on-a-samsung-galaxy-boo

Comment: It might be UEFI and MBR related problem. Check your bios settings or by running Windows partition manager that which prtition table you have on SSD. Then make USB bootable to same partition table. E.g. your SSD is UEFI then make USB Bootable in UEFI.

Comment: It seems like a missing UFS driver in Ubuntu.
the ubuntu doesn't even recognize the block device.

Comment: Does your computer have "Intel RAID" mode set up on it rather than AHCI?  Intel RAID mode is not compatible with Linux and does not work unless your system is set to AHCI for SATA / drive operations

Answer (score 0):

The storage is a UFS flash drive. It is attached to an Intel PCIe UFS card. Unfortunately that card only has some support starting in 5.13. So far I have been unable to get it to function as all access to it just hang on mine.

Incidentally, the keyboard not functioning appears to be a similar issue. The Intel i2c bus that both the keyboard and track pad are attached to is not recognized by the kernel.

**Update:**
The 5.14 kernel was somewhat functional and each kernel release has added better UFS support.

You'll also want https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-gpio/msg66048.html to get the keyboard and track pad working.