# Can not install Ubuntu 21.04 in Samsung Galaxy Boos S Intel Lakefield keyboard, touchpad, and UFS Storage problems

Tags: dual-boot, samsung

I have a notebook Samsung Galaxy Book S Intel i5-L16G7 Lakefield with a UFS Storage SAMSUNG KLUEG8UHDB-C2D1.

I can boot Ubuntu 21.04 from USB Stick but Ubuntu does not recognize the UFS Storage, and the Keyboard / Touchpad does not work.

Using an USB Keyboard / Mouse the system recognize the wi-fi adapter and works well.
Bluetooth adapter does not work.

Answer (score 0):

So the 5.13 kernel recently released actually claims to support the intel UFS on the laptop.

For me it does detect it but when LVM probes it is locking up somehow.

See also: [How do I make the SSD accessible to the Ubuntu installer on a Samsung Galaxy Book S (Intel Lakefield)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320550/how-do-i-make-the-ssd-accessible-to-the-ubuntu-installer-on-a-samsung-galaxy-boo?newreg=ab683cb05e254f26ab8c0a1b85ad72e0)

Update:
The UFS drive now works in kernels >= 5.14 but I suggest newer than that. You will also need https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-gpio/msg66048.html to get the keyboard and trackpad working

Comment: Thank you @ed-schaller 
The UFS Drive works with 5.14. I've finally installed MX Linux AHS with 5.14
The system works fine.

I didn't understand how to make the keyboard and touchpad work.